# square complex number sum

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it possible to demonstrate that

$\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_{j}y_{j}^{*}\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_{j}^{*}y_{j}=|\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_{j}y_{j}^{*}|^{2}$

where * denotes the complex conjugate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $z =\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_{j}y_{j}^{*}$, then the assertion is simply that $$zz^*=|z|^2$$ which is, of course, true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you give me a reference (a link is sufficient) about these rules for complex number? I am struggling in find materials to study

Comment: These are basic properties of complex numbers.  Any book that deals with complex numbers will discuss these at the beginning.

Comment: I know, but I don't have calculus books with this particular properties and library are closed now due to covid.

Comment: Just search the web for "complex numbers", then.  Or try the Kahn Academy.  I don't have a specific source to recommend, sorry.